# Duplicates spawn when trying to watch python-3... tags

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

Updating my watched tags, I wanted to watch `python-3.6` tag, and I was already watching `python` and `python-3.x` tags.

However when I add the tag, I see it added and then it quickly switches to `python-3.x`, and stay next to the real one. It will also point to the same URL and it seems I can indefinitely add other ones this way. I also noticed the same issue with `python-3.7` but not with `python-3.8`, or 3.1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

In a bit different way the `python-3.5.2` has also specific issues: it displays "s" as the number of watchers, I don't know if it's a default value or a weird bug. And when I add it to my watched tags it it switches to only `python-3.5` and points to the same URL. Same thing, I can indefinitely add other ones like this.

Upon refresh, all the duplicates are gone, leaving the true ones only, and so I'm not able to watch the "infected" ones.

A screenshot showing the unlimited duplicates and the "s" amount of `python-3.5.2` watchers. [image: Screenshot of "Adding tags"]

This is an issue for me as I would like to watch some of these tags (`python-3.6` notably).

I don't know if same issues occur for `python2-...` and haven't tried specifying Y in `python-3.X.Y`.

Comment: Wow. Python users like their tag versions... _specific_.

Comment: the Y in `python X.Y.Z` means various new features across versions, and sometimes changing implementation. But I agree that the Z, which is often only for bugfixing and minor changes, may be a bit too much.

Comment: @yivi there's a surprisingly large amount of differences even between separate minor releases.

Comment: The `python-3.5.2` tag is a synonym, not a separate tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.5/synonyms

Comment: Martijn gave a big hint which I believe is the cause of the problem: adding a synonymized tag doesn't trigger the duplicate tag checking. This also includes `python-3.6` and `python-3.7` (the tag info on [`python-3.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/synonyms))

Comment: Well I don't want to criticize but I think that `python-3.6` and `python-3.7` shouldn't be synonyms of `python-3.x`, especially if higher and lower versions aren't.

Comment: And thank you @MartijnPieters this explains the "s" as amount of watchers of 3.5.2. Though in my opinion it should be more explicit, such as `syn.` ; or the amount of the actual tag.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379039/tag-synonyms-are-popping-into-suggestion

Comment: Wait, what? `python-3.6` and `python-3.7` should **not** be synonyms! I'm removing those now, thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: It looks like these synonyms were pushed through sometime late November; we got this reasonably early, so not too much damage was done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's almost two months of auto-retagging from [tag:python-3.6] to `python` and from [tag:python-3.7] to `python`: I do believe there was a lot of damage. Did you check the "Renames" column count of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms before removing the synonyms?

Comment: @Cœur: unfortunately, I didn't, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, we're not Sunday, so it's still [queryable on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967700/python-synonyms): 321 autorenames for `python-3.6` and 309 autorenames for `python-3.7`. But you'll need someone else than me to tell the affected questions.

Comment: @Cœur: only 630 then, that's a very small subset of [nearly 10k python-3.x questions posted in that timeframe](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2018-11-23...2019-01-16+%5Bpython-3.x%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=1). A few targeted queries on top of that search will suffice; adding `3.6` or `3.7` gives me around 650 questions, total.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think I was able to narrow it to [maximum 256 potential edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967722/tags-changed-with-python-3-x-between-2018-11-23-and-2019-01-17), where most of them aren't actually coming from python-3.6 or python-3.7. But some do, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53060589/revisions). If my query is correct, then that makes it human reviewable.

Comment: @Cœur: I've [poked the Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45096160#45096160).

Comment: As I understand the query results might spoil around Sunday, so I pasted the result of [@Cœur's last query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967722/tags-changed-with-python-3-x-between-2018-11-23-and-2019-01-17) into [a gist for safe keeping](https://gist.github.com/adeak/40176d1f741624d6ff11da9371f00c0f). The data dump is more convenient but we can reconstruct a list of relevant URLs from the csv should the need arise.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it's the other way around: my [first query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967700/python-synonyms) about counting autorenames will be obsolete on Sunday (because the two rows we care about will disappear), but my [second query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967722/tags-changed-with-python-3-x-between-2018-11-23-and-2019-01-17) about tracking tag edits will only be mature after this coming Sunday, as it's currently missing some edits between January 12 and January 17.

Comment: @Cœur so much for my understanding :) Thanks, updated the gist with your volatile first query.