# Tag synonyms are popping into suggestion window

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

When I was posting a question with [visual-studio-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-mac) I noticed that [visual-studio-for-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-for-mac) was a suggestion. Being diligent to clean the only question tagged with [visual-studio-for-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-for-mac) question up, the tag page redirected me to [visual-studio-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-mac). I confirmed there is an existing synonym for it which was created in November 2017. Hence either there's some caching (that'd be a long cache window) or some bug in the tag selector query.

[image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379015/duplicates-spawn-when-trying-to-watch-python-3-tags but not a direct duplicate as we can't see if these use the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was one question that had the old tag: [sgen TypeLoadException in Visual Studio for Mac when trying to build Xamarin.iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44331067/). This causes the tag to not get deleted, and then it still shows up as a suggestion. I've retagged that question now.

As Stijn commented here, a merge is separate from a synonym, and apparently as long as the tags aren't merged, the synonym tag doesn't get deleted, and still shows up as a suggestion.

Comment: Why shouldn't the question be able to have that tag? The tag was applied on 2017-06-02 while the synonym was created in November 2017.

Comment: @Stijn When a synonym gets created, all questions with the synonym tag should get retagged to use the master tag, as far as I know, but this one somehow didn't get retagged.

Comment: That's a separate operation known as a tag merge. Merging can only be done by moderators. See [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work).

Comment: @Stijn Ah, would you consider this by-design then? There apparently are some more unmerged synonyms and those show up too as a tag suggestion.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know if merging tag synonyms is part of our moderators' routine currently.